# Errors installing Protractor on MAC OS 10.6

Tags: macos, selenium, npm, protractor

Any help with this installation?

```
$ npm i protractor -g
|
> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1
/usr/local/bin/protractor -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor
/usr/local/bin/webdriver-manager -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager
protractor@2.5.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor
├── jasminewd@1.1.0
├── jasminewd2@0.0.6
├── html-entities@1.1.3
├── q@1.0.0
├── minijasminenode@1.1.1
├── adm-zip@0.4.4
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── jasmine@2.3.2 (exit@0.1.2, jasmine-core@2.3.4)
├── accessibility-developer-tools@2.6.0
├── source-map-support@0.2.10 (source-map@0.1.32)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── saucelabs@1.0.1 (https-proxy-agent@1.0.0)
├── request@2.57.0 (caseless@0.10.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, stringstream@0.0.5, oauth-sign@0.8.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.1, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, node-uuid@1.4.7, combined-stream@1.0.5, qs@3.1.0, form-data@0.2.0, mime-types@2.0.14, tough-cookie@2.2.1, http-signature@0.11.0, bl@0.9.4, har-validator@1.8.0, hawk@2.3.1)
└── selenium-webdriver@2.47.0 (tmp@0.0.24, rimraf@2.4.3, xml2js@0.4.4, ws@0.8.0)
```

Comment: I called sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools and then xcode-select --install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the [*XCode Command Line Tools*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/SpecifyingCommandLineTools/SpecifyingCommandLineTools.html) should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have found it on https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and had to use the great patch from http://kitcambridge.tumblr.com/post/17778742499/installing-the-xcode-command-line-tools-on-snow, but now running `protractor` seems to produce errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762048/protractor-does-run-after-installation

Answer (score 0):

Installing the XCode Command Line Tools really fixes the problem.

The link in the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33745855/4873616) currently leads to XCode help page.

Simplest way to install XCode CLT is to execute in terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```